# Replace 0 with blank in VLOOKUP

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I am using VLOOKUP function to map some data from another worksheet. I was able to do it without an issue but I have few columns which are related to Finance department let's say Amount which should not be reflected with 0 if it's blank in source sheet.

I am using below query which put 0 for blank values.

```
=VLOOKUP(CF2,Sheet1!A:E,FALSE)
```

Column A is ID of transaction and E contains Amounts

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: It would help to see the actual data involved here.

Comment: Sure @TimBiegeleisen I will update question now

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For some security reason, I couldn't upload the data here. Apologies !  I would be appreciate if you can help me on this. :)

Comment: @Amit Make example data or try to explain the problem better then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your issue, You can simply use an If function to replace the blank results by a blank like this:

`=IF(VLOOKUP(CF2,Sheet1!A:E,5,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP(CF2,Sheet1!A:E,5,FALSE))`

Also from A to E there are 5 Columns so I added the "5" Argument in the function.......

Comment: Appreciate ur help, but what if Amount for few transaction is already 0? I want to show 0 if amount is 0 & blank if it is blank

Comment: I have changed the formula, you can check now ;)

Comment: That works like a charm...Thanks billion..Happy Weekend

Comment: Please accept the answer, this is the way to say thank you on Stack overflow ;)